# Xpath selecting nodes with text

Tags: html, xpath

I have 2 requests.

First i need xpath expression that selects all `<tr>` elements with any kind of text nested in that element.
I tried with :

```
//tr[contains(., 'PRVI ODJELJAK')]/following-sibling::tr[text() != '']
```

but it doesnt work it still selects siblings w/o a text also. :/

secondly is there a way to lets say select all siblings of an element until you hit a sibling with inner text matching some text.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Side note: Stackoverflow is a **question & answer** forum, you don't post **requests** here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"First i need xpath expression that selects all  elements with any kind of text nested in that element"*

To filter element that contains some non-whitespace text in it, you can use `normalize-space()` :

```
//tr[contains(., 'PRVI ODJELJAK')]/following-sibling::tr[normalize-space()]
```

> *"secondly is there a way to lets say select all siblings of an element until you hit a sibling with inner text matching some text"*

Probably you can emulate that by selecting *siblings where there is following-sibling with inner text matching some text*

```
following-sibling::tr[following-sibling::tr[contains(.,'some text')]]
```

Comment: thx man sooo much!! Works like a charm. I actually combined both things and it works perfectly. Thx alot!